# Remove 'filename.bib' from pdf output file

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex`, and everything works fine. But, before the references list, in each chapter, in the output `.pdf` file, the filename of my `.bib` file appears.
I'm working with TeXnicCenter and compiling with Miktex 2.9 on Windows 7.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,english]{book}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric, citestyle=numeric-comp, refsection=chapter, sorting=none, hyperref=true, maxnames=20, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}   
\defbibheading{biblatex}{\section*{References}}

\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}    
\usepackage{guit}

\addbibresource{Introduzione/bibintro.bib}    
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle}

\begin{document}    
\chapter{Introduction}

\input{Introduzione/intro.tex}

\printbibliography[heading=biblatex]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't use `\bibliographystyle` with `biblatex`

Comment: I commented the line \bibliographystyle, but I didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I can't see it. Please, make a compilable example.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a redundant command already removed by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution. In my chapter files, I added the line \bibliography{filename.bib}. That was the mistake. I commented that line, and now everything is OK.